# Solidity ParseError with null

Tags: solidity

```
mapping (address => uint) itemsPerCreator;

if (itemsPerCreator[_creator] == null){}
```

> Remix give me a error: ParseError: Expected primary expression.

_creator is a addres type variable. Inside the mapping each addres have a uint value.

Comment: What is `null`?

Comment: The if is inside a function. So I´m trying to evaluate if is a value inside the mapping. That mapping have one a address and a uint value. So im evaluating if the value inside the mapping is null

Comment: It doesn't answer my question - where have you declared a `uint` variable named `null`?

Comment: null is not a variable. Is a value

Comment: Well, whatever, but where have you defined it?

Comment: the null value?? no where

Comment: Well then that's what the compiler is possibly complaining about - an unknown symbol (possibly, because this is obviously just one part of your code; there could be other problems of course). You can replace it with `nothing`, and you'll get the same result.

Comment: And how can I figure if the uint value inside the mapping is a null value or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "null value" (i.e., what `uint` value would you consider to be "null value")?

Comment: I mean that a null value is when and address of the mapping has not uint value added in the mapping.

Comment: Any unmapped value is actually mapped to the zero value of the given type, which in your case is `uint(0)`, or simply `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is nothing like `null` or `undefined` in solidity. An `uint` initializes with 0.

So, to check the zero-state of value(either default or intentionally updated) to the corresponding key in your mapping, you should write it as:

```
if (itemsPerCreator[_creator] == 0){}
```

As per the Solidity [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/control-structures.html#scoping-and-declarations):

> A variable which is declared will have an initial default value whose
>   byte-representation is all zeros. The “default values” of variables
>   are the typical “zero-state” of whatever the type is. For example, the
>   default value for a bool is false. The default value for the uint or
>   int types is 0. For statically-sized arrays and bytes1 to bytes32,
>   each individual element will be initialized to the default value
>   corresponding to its type. Finally, for dynamically-sized arrays,
>   bytes and string, the default value is an empty array or string.

Comment: The part `to check the non-existence of value to the corresponding key in your mapping` is wrong. A value exists, and it is 0. In addition to that, any key mapped to 0 can also be added in an explicit manner.

Comment: @goodvibration You're right, answer updated.